# android firebase list data from node

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Android Application crash when trying to display list of data from firebase

public class exerciseshowactivity extends Activity {

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private Button btnSearch;
private EditText actSearch;
private ListView lvexercise;
Exercise exercise;
String key;

private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList <> ();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_exerciseshow );

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child("Exercise").child(key).child("name");
```

//        DatabaseReference commandsRef = mDatabase.child("Exercise");

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList );

    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.btnSearch );
    actSearch = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.actSearch );
    lvexercise = (ListView) findViewById ( R.id.lvexercise );

    mDatabase.addChildEventListener ( new ChildEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
```

//                Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
//                String string = dataSnapshot.getValue (String.class);

```
            Exercise latest = dataSnapshot.getValue(Exercise.class);

            arrayList.add ( String.valueOf ( latest ) );

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
            lvexercise.setAdapter ( adapter );

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qte9.png)

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add ChildEventListener. There is a firebase library available to populate the listview with the data from your database.

Here is the link, it also has a guide to it.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md